# set focus to textbox in user control c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a user control in c# window forms say chatWindow and it has a textbox with butons. I placed this user control four times on MainForm say uc1, uc2, uc3, uc4. On MainForm I have also other controls. Now I want that when user press TAB then focus of uc1's textbox should be set. Pressing tab second time focus of uc2's textbox should be set and also for 3rd anf 4th tab.

I tried to set TabIndex of these user controls but could not get success. I dont know how to get user control's textbox property while in MainForm.

Comment: Are you just wanting to tab through the usercontrols ignoring the other controls on your form?

Comment: Why not consider setting the tabIndex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a variable to store tab press count, define it inside of Form class in class level:

```
int count = 0;
```

Then in the `Form's` [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event do the following:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
            switch (count)
            {
                case 0:
                    this.ActiveControl = uc1TextBox;
                    count++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.ActiveControl = uc2TextBox;
                    count++
                    break;

               // and so on...
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: uc1TextBox.Focus() can be used too!

Comment: uc1TextBox is in user control but I am in MainForm; how can I get this property ?

Comment: @ZaheerMehmood then try to use textBox's Focus method as mentioned in the previous comment.or maybe your user control has a ActiveControl property try to set that.

Comment: I have instance of user control in MianForm but I am unbale to do like uc1.textbox1.setFocus() etc

Comment: @ZaheerMehmood if you provide some code It would better.I couldn't understand that from your question

Comment: Actually I have objects of user controls uc1, uc2, uc3, uc4 as this user control I used in this form. Let me test your given code

Comment: @Selman22 I am trying your code but Form1_KeyDown is not detecting. what to do ? I think your code will work due to this.ActiveControl = uc ..

Comment: you should set it to your MainForm.Go to designer > properties > events in main form then double click KeyDown event write that code, don write `private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` just body of the method

Comment: @ZaheerMehmood Make sure the Form's KeyPreview property is set to true. If it isn't it will not respond to any KeyEvents

Answer (score 0):

first set tab orders and Ensure that all the controls you want to select have their TabStop property set to true

```
  private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
            e.Handled = true;
            this.ProcessTabKey(true);
    }

  }
```

Comment: uc1TextBox is in user control but I am in MainForm; how can I get this property ?

Comment: I have instance of user control in MianForm but I am unbale to do like uc1.textbox1.setFocus() etc

Answer (score 0):

Try Instead,
Simply, 
In Design Mode, From properties Explorer set tabIndex value of uc1 to 0, uc2 to  1, uc3 to 2, uc4 to 3 and set their tabstop property true.
Hope this is enough.
Thanks.